# CS0246: The type or namespace name 'sconnection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new i asp.net. i create website in asp.net with c# and database sql server 2005 . when i run in visual studio its working fine. But when i run on localhost the error is occurred. Please solve my problem. the error is
Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'sconnection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

```
Line 15: public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
Line 16: {
**Line 17:    sconnection c = new sconnection();**
Line 18:     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
Line 19:     {
```

Source File: d:\SIPLWEB\WebSite\Default.aspx.cs    Line: 17

Thanks

Comment: Can you have your cursor on "sconnection" and press ctrl+shift+F10? It will show you if you have missed the namespace for this class.

Comment: What do you think `sconnection` is?

Comment: In Visual Studio do a Find in Files, look in entire solution for "sconnection". Ensure the References folder for your project includes the project "sconnection" is defined in and, if sconnection is defined in a namespace, that you are `using` that namespace in your project.

Answer (score 1):

are you sure that this is working in Visual Studio?
`sconnection` is no class I ever heard of and from your description I believe that you want something like `SqlConnection`.

If not please give us the full code and search for the class "sconnection" in your project.

Comment: i have make sconnection.cs file for sql connection in app_code folder in project

Comment: why would you put a .cs file into the app_code ... anyhow - did you copy this to your local-apps app_code folder as well?

Answer (score 0):

try to create virtual directory for your web project. To create the virtual directory and application in IIS, click the Create Virtual Directory button next to the Url box as below.

if you do like below, it will add all the required web pages and dlls in a virtual directory. I think you missed on or many required classes when you create virtual directory or IIS web site.

[image: Configuring a Web application project to use IIS]